# Extract JSON data using JSON path

Tags: json, jsonpath, loadrunner, vugen

I am using the following to extract JSON data using JSON path
JSON example:

```
[
 {
  "key": "value1",
  "label": "Auto - some random hash value..1"
 
 },
 {
  "key": "value2",
  "label": "Agro - some random hash value...2"
 },
 {
  "key": "value3",
  "label": "Auto - some random hash value...2"
 },
 {
  "key": "valuen",
  "label": "Textile - some random hash value...n"
 }
]
```

I am trying to extract data value label in array index by applying condition to peers key in same index

1. query : extract label where key = value2
2. query : extract label where label starts with Auto

for query 2, I gave a try with following JSONPath but not getting expected result.
$.[?(@.label =~ /^Auto.*/)]

Comment: try
$[?(@.label.indexOf('Auto') === 0)].label - for auto
$[?(@.key == 'value2')].label - for value2

Comment: @ASisic thanks a lot. Above solution worked. Would you explain how does indexOf() works with === as value 0.

Comment: Method returns the index at which the substring 'Auto' is found within the given string.
The indexOf('Auto') === 0 condition ensures that 'Auto' is at the beginning of the 'label' string. If it's not at the beginning, the condition will evaluate to false, and that element won't be included in the result.

Comment: What have you tried in the correlation universe for HTTP virtual users?  There are likely multiple paths to the answer you seek

Comment: Thanks @james Pully. I was specifically looking for Json Extracator

Comment: web_reg_save_param_json(). https://admhelp.microfocus.com/vugen/en/2022-2022-r2/help/function_reference/Content/FuncRef/web/lrFr_web_reg_save_param_json.htm